# Sharing private YouTube Live with a Gmail mailing list

Tags: youtube, sharing, youtube-live

I'm trying to share a private YouTube Live broadcast with a Gmail alias that has 200+ people on it.

Will YouTube allow sharing with a mail/distribution list, or do I have to enter each email one by one?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube needs to authenticate the individuals watching the video and for that they use the person's Google account. So yes, if you make your stream private, you'll need to enter each address individually.

However, on that scale, you may want to use an unlisted stream instead and trust that your mailing list members won't share it. Or use a different service that has domain restrictions or password protection or so (eg. Vimeo Live).

Comment: Or use a csv. You can copy and paste emails in comma separated format.

Comment: @61897 Really? How? I typed 'AAA@gmail.com, BBB@gmail.com'. It couldn't work that only AAA@gmail.com was inserted. Could you teach me?

Comment: @OODWaterball After pasting the email address separated by ", " - just press the spacebar. I posted this with an example here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168636/306720

Answer (score 0):

I solve it easily. You can try to use comma to separated the email address e.g.

> AAA@example,BBB@example

NO spacing between the email!

---

For converting multiple emails to one line and adding the comma for the end of each email, main idea:

1. Copy and paste multiple emails to Google Excel in a column
2. Add comma for the end of each email, if A1 is email, in B1 type `=A1&","`
3. Concatenate the email to one line, B1 to B5 are the email end with comma, use`=CONCATENATE(B1:B5)`