# How do you share a private YouTube video to lots of people quickly?

Tags: youtube, video

I have to share 6 YouTube videos with more than 60 people but privately. Is there a better way to do this faster so that I don't have to paste them into each video one at a time? It's impossible to paste multiple at once as it treats it as one and says there's an error.

It has to be private a private video and I don't want to paste an email 360 times.

Comment: have you considered posting the 6 videos to a (free) Dropbox (or similar) account in a Public folder and then emailing the link to the folder to your intended recipients?

Comment: thanks for the idea, but each video is about an hour long, and the storage space for that is quite big. I just gritted my teeth and pasted all the emails already, so this question is mostly a hypothetical at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been flustered with this, as it would have been so reasonable if it had worked like Gmail's address line.

**But, gladly I found a working solution:**

- Paste all the desired emails with commas and spaces separating them (i.e. `ab@cd.com, ef@gh.com, ...`) in the input field "Share video privately" in Youtube studio
- Then press the spacebar, and voila!
- Be aware, they must have their own Youtube accounts and the maximum number is 50 usernames. **Update:** I managed to share with more than 50 users, and I can't find any user limit mentioned officially.

**Bonus:**
If you have a large list (for example from google sheets or excel), you will probably end up after copy-and-paste with a list of emails separated by line breaks. To replace the line break with ", " you can use your favorite regex-supporting text editor. In the second screen capture you can see I'm using VScode to search "\n" for line breaks (this is regex) and replacing it with ", "

This is what it looks like at the end:
[image]

This is how I'm replacing line breaks with ", " (don't forget to press the spacebar after pasting in Youtube):
[image]